# How do you make a new, searchable metadata schema for DSpace?

Tags: schema, metadata, dspace

So DSpace uses dublin core by the default and apparently you cannot touch that schema; since I am creating a collection of images, I want to create an IPTC schema. So I went to "Metadata" under Registries and clicked on "Add new schema". I named it and went ahead with adding fields. I've added a few to my first submission only to realize that they are essentially useless. I can't search with them. For example, if my dublin core title field says "Image a" but my IPTC title field says "John Smith", searching for John and/or Smith turns up nothing.

What is the appropriate way to make this a functional schema?

Answer (score 4):

After adding schemas or fields to your DSpace, you likely need to re-create your SOLR Discovery index, before you can use these fields for search and browse

In DSpace 5, try

```
[dspace]/bin/dspace index-discovery -f
```

More information:
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Discovery#Discovery-DiscoverySolrIndexMaintenance

If you are using a different DSpace version, make sure to check the Discovery documentation page for your version of DSpace, as the syntax of these commands has evolved over different versions.

Comment: Shouldn't you also [add the new indexes to dspace.cfg](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Configuration+Reference#ConfigurationReference-DefiningtheIndexes) before re-indexing?

Comment: I did add them by following the information here: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Modify+search+fields

However, they are still not functioning and I am having difficulty locating the correct way to re-create my SOLR Directory (several different commands didn't work). The last bit of help my professor provided was to go back to my metadata registry and find the corresponding field names in DSpace to make them searchable.

Comment: Patricio, I think that only applies if you want to create a specific "browse by" index for that field. I don't think this is necessary for your field to make it into the general search index, but I could be wrong.

Comment: kbau I would be careful with the info on that page if I were you. First of all, it hasn't been updated since 2013. Second of all, it's not part of the /DSDOC5x or /DSDOC6x space, where you can find the official docs for a particular version.